# Google Cloud Speech API add SpeechContext

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

I would like to add some keywords to my app, so the API can recognize more efficiently the spoken words.
For example I`m having trouble recognizing the some Italian words that starts with E` ,(E` per me) for example. Or in German (er geht).

Here is my code:

```
public void recognize (int sampleRate) {
    if (mApi == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "API not ready. Ignoring the request.");
        return;
    }
    // Configure the API
    mRequestObserver = mApi.streamingRecognize(mResponseObserver);
    mRequestObserver.onNext(StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setStreamingConfig(StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setLanguageCode(getDefaultLanguageCode())
                            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                            .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRate)
                            .build())
                    .setInterimResults(true)
                    .setSingleUtterance(true)
                    .build())
            .build());
}
```

Setting the language for different cases :

```
private String getDefaultLanguageCode() {

    SharedPreferences getLangSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("langSelected",0);
    String selectedLanguage = getLangSharedPrefs.getString("langSelected", null);
    switch (selectedLanguage) {
        case "German":
            langaugeCode = "de-DE";
            break;
        case "Italian":
            langaugeCode = "it-IT";
            break;
        case "Spanish" :
            langaugeCode = "es-ES";
            break;
        case "French" :
            langaugeCode = "fr-FR";
            break;
    }
    return langaugeCode;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
 public void startRecognizing(int sampleRate) {
    if (mApi == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "API not ready. Ignoring the request.");
        return;
    }
    // Configure the API
    mRequestObserver = mApi.streamingRecognize(mResponseObserver);
    SpeechContext.Builder speechBuilder = SpeechContext.newBuilder();
    speechBuilder.addPhrases("E per me");
    speechBuilder.addPhrases("E");
    mRequestObserver.onNext(StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setStreamingConfig(StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setLanguageCode(getDefaultLanguageCode())
                            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                            .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRate)
                            .addSpeechContexts(speechBuilder)
                            .build())
                    .setInterimResults(true)
                    .setSingleUtterance(true)
                    .build())
            .build());
}
```